# byte[] to wav file

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

It would be great if you could tell me how I could save a byte[] to a wav file. Sometimes I need to set different samplerate, number of bits and channels.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It would be great if you could tell us what you've tried or what you have so far.

Comment: Well what's the content of the byte array?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up the wav header data which contains info about sample rate, file size, sample size, stereo or mono etc. Then write the actual audio data.
Then you just have to write it out as a binary file with '.wav' file extension.